# Connecting SQL Server with Power BI and Power Automate

Tags: powerbi, ssms, power-automate

I am trying to insert data into my SQL Server database in SSMS using Power BI Desktop and Power Automate. I have successfully imported a test table from my database into Power BI. Now, I want to automate the process using Power Automate by adding an "Update Row" step. However, when I choose Windows Authentication, it prompts for a username and password, which I don't have access to.

I would like to know the best approach to connect SQL Server with Power BI and Power Automate. Is there a way to achieve this and perform a simple query through Power Automate? I would greatly appreciate any guidance or step-by-step instructions on how to set up the connection securely and efficiently. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

there are connectors you can use by going to your Power Automate Page > Connectors > Create a new SQL Connector and then you'll be able to Insert a row in a SQL table via your Power Automate, for Power BI, there is a Power Automate connector inside it as well. I hope this helps a little bit.